# Properly handle Firebase event listeners in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wondering where should i put my Firebase global event listener like on().

I want to init some listener when the app launch, like listening to the add of a post and then modifying the components which display the latest post.

I thought about creating a class that i would call when the app launch, init all the listeners and dispatch them trought Redux, but redux connect need a component, not a class.

Should i just create a component with no a render function empty and handle my events in it ?

Or should i put my listeners directly in the components that gonna us these data ?

Answer (score 0):

You have add

```
on(‘child_added’, ()=>{
//Your want to set of reaction. For example your action creator.
//When the child add to your realtime database, here will work.
})
```

to Main.js or index.ios.js
When the open the app, this listeners will start to work.